# localhost web page won't display (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303)

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I am running apache 2.4.9 with Xampp 1.8.3-4 on my mac. I am building another website within dreamweaver and never came across this problem before:

When I try to display one of my page in the browser via localhost (either chrome or safari), the browser says it is inaccessible. All the other pages display just fine. Safari displays the error :

> kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.

The xampp application log doesn't show any error. And I don't really know how to solve this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It usually appears when you try to `POST` while the server expects `GET` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by changing the recordset created with the dreamweaver wizard to match the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, your answer helped me looking the right way.

I in fact had made changes to the mySQL database. This had created the error when I modified my recordset in dreamweaver to match the database. Since then, I dropped a table but forgot to modify the recordset so it matched the database again.

Now everything is fine.